# Creating Navs for multiple directories

Tags: php, html, nav

Is it possible to create a nav that link to multiple directories and files in `php`,I don't want to update the link on each page when I change any one link

Those are my pages:

```
1) index.php
2) example.php
3) example2.php
4) example/index.php
5) example2/index.php
```

I want to have single nav for all above files. (Is it possible?)

//-------- Edit ----------

I don't want to start the links with "/". It looks a bit unprofessional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if You don't want to use absolute path (with "/"), than You need to use  "../" to find path. Try:

```
<?php //------------ nav.php ------------
$slashcount = substr_count($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/'); // count '/' in 
$dir = str_repeat('../', $slashcount -1); //    maybe needs to subtract with 2
?>
<ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="<?php echo $dir; ?>index.php">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo $dir; ?>example.php">example</a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo $dir; ?>example2php">example2</a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo $dir; ?>example/index.php">example3</a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo $dir; ?>example2/index.php">example4</a></li>
</ul>
```

to call in index.php.

> include "nav.php";

and inside of example/index.php

> include "../nav.php";

Answer (score 0):

this is so easy you just need to create a file which include to your each page like that.

create file `navigation.php`

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="index.php">Home</a>
    <li><a href="example.php">example</a>
    <li><a href="example2php">example2</a>
    <li><a href="example3.php">example3</a>
    <li><a href="example4.php">example4</a>
</ul>
```

new include your navigation file into every single page like that.

in index.php

```
include "navigation.php";
```